# excel 2007 vba Sum cells in row not working

Tags: vba, excel, sum, excel-2007

I am new to this group and know only a little about VBA.

I have a number of worksheets in a spreadsheet. Data from a report is loaded to worksheet 'data'. The number of rows can vary. My macro needs to copy certain columns from worksheet 'data' to another worksheet called 'T2'. Once 'T2' is populated, I need to sum cells 'N' to 'S' and put the result in cell 'M'. This needs to happen on each individual row from row 3 to the end of the worksheet. The 'copy' function from worksheet 'data' to worksheet 'T2' works OK, but I just can't get the SUM function to work. The nearest I got (in that it at least wiped the content of the cells in column "M") is as below. There are two sets of command lines commented out. The first is the 'copy' set as they work. The second are the variations of SUM command that I have already tried. Many thanks for reading this.

```
Sub Copy_range()

Sheets("data").Activate


    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim iRow As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    End With
 '   MsgBox LastRow

'Worksheets("data").Range("A1:G" & LastRow).Copy
'Worksheets("T2").Range("E2").PasteSpecial

'Worksheets("data").Range("J1:AA" & LastRow).Copy
'Worksheets("T2").Range("N2").PasteSpecial




With Application.WorksheetFunction

Sheets("T2").Activate


     For iRow = 3 To LastRow + 1

     'Cells(iRow, "M") = Cells(iRow, "N") + Cells(iRow, "O") + Cells(iRow, "P") + Cells(iRow, "Q") + Cells(iRow, "R") + Cells(iRow, "S")

     'ActiveSheet.Cells(iRow, "M") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Cells(iRow, "N"), Cells(iRow, "S")))

     'ActiveSheet.Cells(iRow, "M").Value = Sum((iRow & N):(iRow & S))

     ' BEST SO FAR: Worksheets("T2").Cells(iRow, "M").Value = Application.Sum(Range(Cells(iRow, "N"), Cells(iRow, "S")))

     Worksheets("T2").Cells(iRow, "M").Value = Application.Sum(Range(Cells(iRow, "N"), Cells(iRow, "S")))

     'Worksheets("T2").Cells(iRow, "M").Value = "=SUM(" & Range(Cells(iRow, "N"), Cells(iRow, "S")) & ")"

'Range("A1").Formula = "=SUM(" & Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(3, 2)).Address(False, False) & ")"



     Next iRow


  End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing

```
Worksheets("T2").Cells(iRow, "M").Value = Application.Sum(Range(Cells(iRow, "N"), Cells(iRow, "S")))
```

with

```
Worksheets("T2").Cells(iRow, "M").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC[1]:RC[6])"
```

should work, I think.

Not on my workcomputer right now, so I can't test it, but. I suspect that part of your problem is that you don't specify what worksheet the cells you want to sum are on at the right side of your equal-sign. Personally I like to always state explicitly both what worksheet and range I am working with, to avoid confusion.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this - it seems to work!  I think your assessment regarding not identifying the worksheet in the right hand side of the equation was correct as I had already proved to myself that the left hand side worked. I suppressed the 'copy worksheet' code so that I could populate column "M" manually to see what happened, and when I ran the code it was being overwritten with zeros. Therefore, it knew where to put it - it just didn't know what to put there. Thanks very much for your help.